# Insert string or comment into vcd dump file

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

Is there any generic way to insert a comment (or probably any string) into a vcd dump?
For example in below code, I want to insert some comment when `a` changes to `1`:

```
module test;
    reg a;
    initial begin
        $dumpfile("dump.vcd");
        $dumpvars(1,test.a);
        end
    initial begin
        a = 0;
        #10;
        // insert_vcd_string("MY_STRING", dump.vcd);
        a = 1;
        #10;
        end
endmodule
```

Comment: How do you want to be able to view the string?

Comment: It doesn't have to be shown in waveform. I just want to see it in text format, i.e when I open the file using text editor.

Comment: Why does it need to be in a VCD file? How about a log files using system tasks and functions such as `$display` or `$fwrite` as defined in [IEEE Std 1800-2012](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf) § 21

Comment: It may be used for those applications that can only read vcd file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no standard system task to write a comment string into a vcd file although `$comment` is a vcd keyword for creating comment sections:

From [IEEE Std 1800-2012 LRM](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf):

```
$comment This is a single-line comment $end 
$comment This is a 
multiple-line comment 
$end
```

I would experiment with $dumpoff, $dumpflush, and $dumpon. $dumpoff and $dumpoon leave a mark in the vcd file with a timestamp, i.e. `#time $dumpoff ... $end`:

Example from [IEEE Std 1800-2012 LRM](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf):

```
#1000
$dumpoff 
x*@ 
x*# 
x*$ 
bx (k 
bx {2 
$end

#2000
$dumpon 
z*@ 
1*# 
0*$ 
b0 (k 
bx {2 
$end
```

You can toggle between dumpoff/on whenever `a` changes to `1`, and do a post processing of the vcd file to insert a `$comment ... $end` between them.

Comment: Thanks, since there is no standard way, I think this trick is good for me.

Answer (score 1):

The [IEEE Std 1800-2012](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf) does not specify any function for inserting a comment into a VCD file.

You could resort to something like creating a variable with a long name that looks like your string, but this will only appear in the header section, not at any specified time.  For example, in your Verilog code:

```
reg here_is_my_string;
```

This will show up in your VCD file as something like:

```
$var reg       1 "    here_is_my_string  $end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Modelsim/Questa, you can do

```
 initial begin
        a = 0;
        #10;
        mti_fli::mti_Command("vcd comment MY_STRING");
        a = 1;
        #10;
        end
```

or since you are already using SystemVerilog

```
    import mti_fli::*;
    string comment;
     initial begin
                a = 0;
                #10;
                comment = "MY_STRING";
                mti_Command({"vcd comment ",comment});
                a = 1;
                #10;
                end
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, unfortunately I need something that works across any simulator.

Comment: That's not possible without a lot of post processing scripts since VCD does not support strings nor does Verilog/SystemVerilog have a standard way of adding comments for the source text. I'm guessing other simulators have a similar capability that you could ifdef into the source.